# How to handle a list which contains elements having leading zeros?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist

I have a `data` which is coming from another source in the form of a nested list which looks as below:

```
data = [
    ["store1", 50, 02132020], 
    ["store2", 20, 02112020], 
    ["store3", 25, 02172020]
]
```

Here, `50` is the `price`.

And, `02152022` is the `date.`

When, I print the data, I get below error:

`leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers`

How to deal with list whose elements may contain `"leading zeros"`?

Comment: Is the nested list created from a `JSON` source by any chance? What is the source?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you may cast the third element in the list into string, then using datetime to cast into datetime object since it's a date.

I don't know the exact source of `data`. Firstly, It cannot be a vanilla python list object since it cannot pass interpreter check. Secondly, It also maked nonsense as a JSON object. Something like `02132020` are not allowed to appear in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

data = [
    ["store1", 50, "02132020"], 
    ["store2", 20, "02112020"], 
    ["store3", 25, "02172020"]
]

for i in data:
    print({
        "store_name" : i[0],
        "price": i[1],
        "date":(datetime.datetime.strptime(i[2], '%m%d%Y')).date()
    })
```

Output:

```
{'store_name': 'store1', 'price': 50, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 2, 13)}
{'store_name': 'store2', 'price': 20, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 2, 11)}
{'store_name': 'store3', 'price': 25, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 2, 17)}
```